# How to detect if most characters are in Arabic or in Latin inside div?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, arabic, right-to-left

I want to add direction attribute RTL/LTR to DIVs or Paragraphs HTML tags depending on the most characters count whether it is  Arabic or Latin characters.

I'm trying to do it through JavaScript and looking for the characters through regex.

I found this on GitHub https://github.com/miladd3/automatic-direction/blob/master/automatic-direction.js
which would do exactly what I want but its only working for input forms.

I don't know JS, I can not figure out how to use the same code from GitHub to count the characters inside HTML tags and add the RTL/LTR attribute.

Any help would be appreciated very much.

Answer (score 3):

To make that script work for all elements with a class of `.dir-auto`, you would change it like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var elements = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.dir-auto'));
    elements.forEach(function(el) {
        var text = el.innerText,
            farsiChars = text.match(/[\u0600-\u06FF]/g),
            spaceChars = text.match(/\s/g),
            count = text.length,
            farsiCount = farsiChars ? farsiChars.length : 0
            spaceCount = spaceChars ? spaceChars.length : 0,
            latinCount = count - farsiCount - spaceCount;
        el.setAttribute('dir', (farsiCount > latinCount) ? 'rtl' : 'ltr');
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello this is not working can you please be more specific?

Here is the script from GitHub http://jsfiddle.net/gcwj6u53/9/

Comment: Include this script on your page and add `class="dir-auto"` to every element where you want it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/qh41cLsn/

Comment: Now the textarea wouldn't work. Is there a way to make both work?

Comment: Include both scripts